# Bug UPPER(variable)

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to check if a postal code is valid. The postal code in the sample code is NOT valid. So it should not return any values.

```
postcode := '1059NJ';
SELECT P.POSTCODE INTO test3
FROM POSTCODE P
WHERE P.POSTCODE = UPPER(postcode)
AND P.CITY = INITCAP(LOWER('Amsterdam'))
AND P.STREET = INITCAP(LOWER('Aalsmeerweg'))
AND 14 BETWEEN P.MINNUMBER AND P.MAXNUMBER
AND( NUMBERTYPE = 'even' OR NUMBERTYPE = 'mixed');
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(test3);
```

However, instead of returning nothing, it returns this

```
1059AJ
```

That is the valid postal code. It shouldn't have done that.

Here comes the funny bit, if I were to put the postal code inside the '' signs it actually doesn't return anything.

```
SELECT P.POSTCODE INTO test4
FROM POSTCODE P
WHERE P.POSTCODE = UPPER('1059NJ')
AND P.CITY = INITCAP(LOWER('Amsterdam'))
AND P.STREET = INITCAP(LOWER('Aalsmeerweg'))
AND 14 BETWEEN P.MINNUMBER AND P.MAXNUMBER
AND( NUMBERTYPE = 'even' OR NUMBERTYPE = 'mixed');
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(test4);
```

Is this an Oracle bug?

Comment: Try naming your `postcode` variable something other than a column name on your input table.

Comment: This actually works, thanks a lot! I have been stuck on this for hours.

Comment: Not relevant, but why `initcap(lower())` raher than just `initcap()`? The `lower()` seems a bit pointless. Even if you don't really have string literals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Mr Llama hinted, this is a scope issue. Within your SQL statement the plain `postcode` is interpreted first as a column name, and since there is such a column that is used. Lack of an alias qualifier (`p.`) does not preclude the value being taken from that table, or promote the local variable to be used above the column name. So you are really saying:

```
WHERE P.POSTCODE = UPPER(p.postcode)
```

... which isn't what you want, and means that clause will always evaluate to true for any uppercase value.

[From the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/nameresolution.htm#LNPLS2038):

> If a SQL statement references a name that belongs to both a column and either a local variable or formal parameter, then the column name takes precedence.

The simplest answer is to rename your local variable, and it's common to have a naming convention that enforces this; for example prefixing formal parameters with `p_`, local variables with `l_` etc.

If this is in a named block you can also prefix the variable with that name; so if your function is called `IsPostcodeValid` then you can do:

```
WHERE P.POSTCODE = UPPER(IsPostCodeValid.postcode)
```

A naming convention is simpler, shorter and clearer (IMO), but you can always combine both if you want, and refer to `IsValidPostcode.p_postcode` for extra explicitness...